# call external function at the end of simulation in dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there a way to call an external function right before finishing a simulation in dymola? I need to call the destroyer of some objects before terminating the simulation, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use the `terminal()` function as condition

```
when terminal() then
...
end when;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer you might consider switching to ExternalObject:

https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33Revision1.pdf
Section 12.9.7.

One major difference is that if your simulation fails then external objects will be destroyed, but 'when terminal()' will not be called.